# Rails 5 and MongoDB: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, cloud9-ide

I am trying to set up MongoDB with Rails 5. I'm using Cloud9 which seems to automatically set you up to use SQLite, so I'm having some problems with that. I have installed MongoDB and added it to my gem file.

When I run

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

I get the error:

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)

Here is database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I'm not sure how to re-write this for MongoDB? I think I also need to remove or disable ActiveRecord but I'm not sure how to do this in Rails 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your generated application then generate a new rails application with `--skip-active-record` option.

```
rails new your-project --skip-active-record
```

Then add mongo adapter to your Gemfile and so on.

Comment: I tried to remove the generated app but in Cloud9 it doesn't seem to work too well. I deleted the file via the terminal (since I can't via file tree). It's not there anymore in the terminal but it's still in the file tree even after I refresh it. When I created the new app, that didn't appear in the file tree either. I think it would be better to just remove ActiveRecord from the existing app.

Comment: Actually what I'll do is just delete all the contents of the workspace folder rather than the workspace folder itself... That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

*database.yml*

```
development: &global_settings
  database: textual_development
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

test:
  database: textual_test
  <<: *global_settings

production:
  host: hostname
  database: databasename
  username: username
  password: password
  <<: *global_settings
```

Then create an initializer in config/initializers called mongo.rb

*mongo.rb*

```
MongoMapper.setup(Rails.configuration.database_configuration, Rails.env, :logger => Rails.logger)
```

Enjoy!